# Translations of 主编 and 总编 in French

Tags: translation, mandarin, simplified-characters

大家好，

我想翻译这些词。背景是一个杂志社的。
我知道 **总编** 就是 *rédacteur en chef* 可是 关于 **主编** 我莫名其妙。我早想到把它翻译成 *éditeur* 或者 *éditeur en chef* 不过我不太肯定。原来，对记者的专业词汇不太熟悉。因此，我需要你们的帮助。
若有人知道，就告诉我啊。
多谢！

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking for a French translation

Comment: What ? But those are Chinese terms ! It’s not off topic

Comment: wondering why the OP used 帮衬 instead of 帮助 or 帮忙 - it's probably above my head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**主编**

*Grand Ricci*

> Rédacteur en chef (d'un ouvrage collectif).

*KEF*

> 1 rédacteur en chef, compilateur en chef
>   2 éditer (une publication)

*FLTRP*

> rédacteur en chef

*CFDICT*

> 1 rédacteur en chef
>   2 diriger la rédaction

---

**总编**

*CFDICT*

> rédacteur en chef (de journal)

---

Also:

Wikipedia's page for [总编辑](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E7%B8%BD%E7%B7%A8%E8%BC%AF) mirrors to the french page for [Rédacteur en chef](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9dacteur_en_chef). But the original Chinese page does also mention:

> 总编辑，也称总编、主编

So it looks like the Chinese terms are quite interchangeable amongst themselves. 主编 also redirects to the page for 总编辑. I would try not to get too caught up in the semantics of the words.

---

This seems to be quite a complicated question actually. It's quite a hard one to translate properly and it depends on the context. You can see here for more info [here](https://share.america.gov/zh-hans/editors/). According to the article one way of translating these back into English is:

- 主编 = Managing editor
- 总编 = Executive editor

So 主编 might be something like Chef d'édition.

Comment: This seems to be quite a complicated question actually. It's quite a hard one to translate properly and it depends on the context. You can see here for more info: https://share.america.gov/zh-hans/editors/

Comment: It’s not easy indeed. Thanks for your input, I appreciate that. Yes, at first I wanted to translate 总编 as rédacteur en chef and 主编 as chef d’édition. Plus, it seems to me that 总编 is the person in charge and supervises 主编, right ? Plus there’s only one rédacteur en chef but there can be many chef d’édition, am I right ?

Comment: Actually I just nailed it ! Directeur de la rédaction :  总编and  主编 is rédacteur en chef ! 谢谢你 